# How to deal the close list when using A star algorithm

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, a-star

Recently, I was working on A-star algorithm, and after lots of relevant research on the Internet， I am confused.

Someone said when there is a successor which is already in the closelist, we just ignore it, but someone said we need to deal with the closelist

There are two different pesuedocodes

```
Create a node containing the goal state node_goal.
Create a node containing the start state node_start.
Put node_start on the open list.
while the OPEN list is not empty
{
    Get the node off the open list with the lowest f and call it node_current
    if node_current is the same state as node_goal we have found the solution; break from the while loop
    Generate each state node_successor that can come after node_current
    for each node_successor of node_current
    {
        Set the cost of node_successor to be the cost of node_current plus the cost to get to node_successor from node_current
        find node_successor on the OPEN list
        if node_successor is on the OPEN list but the existing one is as good or better then discard this successor and continue
        if node_successor is on the CLOSED list but the existing one is as good or better then discard this successor and continue
        Remove occurences of node_successor from OPEN and CLOSED
        Set the parent of node_successor to node_current
        Set h to be the estimated distance to node_goal (Using the heuristic function)
         Add node_successor to the OPEN list
    }
    Add node_current to the CLOSED list
}
```

---

```
Get the square on the open list which has the lowest score. Let’s call this square S.
Remove S from the open list and add S to the closed list.
For each square T in S’s walkable adjacent tiles:
If T is in the closed list: Ignore it.
If T is not in the open list: Add it and compute its score.
If T is already in the open list: Check if the F score is lower when we use the current generated path to get there. If it is, update its score and update its parent as well.
```

I don't know which one is right，hoping hear some advice from you.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks  for editing. Codor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the first description at all. It is confusing and wrong, at least under some interpretations. The very fact that it can be interpreted in different ways makes it bad. I suggest you use the second.

> Someone said when there is a successor which is already in the closelist, we just ignore it, but someone said we need to deal with the closelist

If it's in the closed list, you ignore it.

```
14 if node_successor is on the CLOSED list but the existing one is as good 
   or better then discard this successor and continue
```

This causes it to be ignored. If a node is in the closed list, it will always be better than or as good as what you have now (unless the preconditions of the algorithm are not met, such as having no negative cost edges).

I agree that it is confusing however, they should have just said:

```
14 if node_successor is on the CLOSED list then discard this successor and continue
```

Also:

```
15 Remove occurences of node_successor from OPEN and CLOSED
```

There is no need to do this. In fact, it gets added to the open list again later. You can explain the algorithm with removals, but it just makes it more difficult to grasp IMO.

This can also be interpreted as allowing a node to enter the closed list multiple times, which is not something the classical A* algorithm allows.

The first pseudocode also does not mention distance updates very clearly.

I suggest you use the second pseudocode. It's much more concise and clear, and definitely correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @IVIad. It helps me a lot. I will use the second one.<br/> This morning, I also asked my tutor, he said _if we are doing the tree search instead of the graph search, we just add the duplicate successor(same coordinate different parent) to the openList_. So now combine that with your answer, it is clearly more.

Comment: If the graph is directed, it is possible for a parallel edge(node->node weight) to have a lower cost than a previously evaluated edge. If the graph is un-directed this edge has already been evaluated but the cost may be different based on the heuristic and the way in which weight is determined. From a computational standpoint, I would not maintain two maps but instead maintain a single map with the node containing a closed boolean value since the better solutions requires checking both maps.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the heuristic function is consistent or not. A heuristic function is consistent if

```
h(y) <= h(x) + w(x, y) for all edges (x,y)
```

If the heuristic is consistent then we never have to revisit the closed set. Otherwise, we may have to revisit the nodes in the closed set, since their costs could be further lowered. Most of the heuristics in practice seem to satisfy consistency, so algorithm B is often good enough to compute the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you need find best path , you should update your close list.
because close list g(x) value reducing may affects his successors in open list.
if you don't update your close list, you can also find a acceptable way.
(end point g(x) is not best value)